# I want to use circle progress bar in my Android project

Tags: android

I want to access this github circle progress bar in my android project , but i don't know how to import this bcoz i never used this things ever so anyone can help ? https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Comment: Download the project by clicking on 'Download Zip' button and use it!!

Comment: @Russell i have a project if i download this zip then how to use it ?

Comment: Try using the code or icluding used in the project!

Comment: even it has download where i can download apk file but i don't know how to use it in my project

Comment: @Russell is there a way to import as a module ? the apk file ?

Comment: I am lost.. what did you downloaded from there? .apk or .zip file

Comment: than what should i do ?

Comment: If you want that apk file check the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/master/demos/example.apk

Comment: What is bcoz? are you using gradle?

Comment: how to use this apk file in my project ?

Comment: yes i am using gradle! i am new to android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compile dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}
```

I will give one example, If you want to use `DonutProgress`, then in `XML`, It looks like this

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And in java it looks like

```
  Timer timer;

  donutProgress = (DonutProgress) findViewById(R.id.donut_progress);       

timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                donutProgress.setProgress(donutProgress.getProgress() + 1);

            }
        });
    }
}, 1000, 100);
```

You can just try others yourself by seeing the codes and usage.

Copied vertabim from the [example project](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/github/lzyzsd/circleprogressexample/MyActivity.java)

Comment: thanks but when i tried doing this in gradle and used xml but it gives me error at  custom:donut_progress="30" it says unbound prefix

Comment: ?? shree you there ?

Comment: Thats the namespace declaration just remove that line.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Bipinp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 this is my error

Comment: OK I've edited my answer, If any problem raised with this, leave comment because I am leaving now for few hours. I m sorry for that

Comment: @bipin I tested it in my device and it worked perfectly fine. Just copy my solution, If it force to make the donutprogress final or others final then declare that variable as class variable.

Comment: i created a navigation drawer and then i created another class where i use drawer and use that class to share the navigation drawer in all my activities , when i share the navigation drawer its working in my another activity but it hides the content of my activity(xml)

Comment: here is the link of my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970435/extending-another-class-and-inflating-its-xml-in-my-current-activity-hides-the-c

Comment: please let me what changes i need to do ?