# extending another class and inflating its xml in my current activity hides the content of my current activity

Tags: android

I have created a navigationactivity where i am having navigation drawer and now when i extend this class in another activities its working but the content of other actvities are not getting displayed

```
here is my code:
package com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Abstract;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.ChartStyle;
import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.Contact;
import com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity.Settings;
import com.astro.famouspandit.R;

public  class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    protected FrameLayout mFrameLayout_ContentFrame;
    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    protected Toolbar mToolbar;
    private LinearLayout mDrawerList2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        mFrameLayout_ContentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_content_frame);
        mDrawerList2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer2);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_DrawerLayout);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(R.color.colorPrimary);

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                (
                        this,
                        mDrawerLayout,
                        mToolbar,
                        R.string.drawer_open,
                        R.string.drawer_close
                ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // Disables the burger/arrow animation by default
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList2);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_Aboutus).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;


    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int items = item.getItemId();
        switch(items){

            case R.id.action_Settings:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Contact_us:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,Contact.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Aboutus:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;

            case R.id.action_Profile:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChartStyle.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer2"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"

        android:background="#0F6177"/>

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

class where i am extending it: i cannot see the content of this class

```
public class Contact extends NavigationActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText mName,mNumber,mEmail,mMessage;
    private FancyButton mSbmt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_contact,mFrameLayout_ContentFrame);
```

Comment: only extending the activity won't show it's content. It will let you use the methods and fields of parent.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna i used inflater to get the xml too getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_contact,mFrameLayout_ContentFrame);

Comment: @ShreeKrishna can you please help i am stucked and getting no help from 2 days

Comment: Are you willing to change the content but want to use all the behavior of `NavigationActivity` ?

Comment: i want to use the behaiver of NavigationActivity and i also want the content of my activity

Comment: my activity means activity_contact ?

Comment: yes it means activity_contact

Comment: OK I will elaborate more in answer that may help you...

Comment: @ShreeKrishna ohk thanks

Comment: @ShreeKrishna can you customize my code and solve this error

Comment: Is this what you were searching of ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for the hierarchy used in the concept of `BaseActivity` you can make many child and use the behavior of parent. The formal concept is pass the layout from child Activity to the `BaseActivity` and `BaseActivity` will set the content.

First create an abstract class and name it `BaseActivity`, It should be something like

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();
}
```

Then in your case extend `BaseActivity` in `NavigationActivity` like here

```
   public class NavigationActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        // do extra stuff on your resources, using findViewById on your activity_navigation
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_navigation;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have created a BaseActivity class with name of AbstractActivity.class

Comment: Should i show you the code of AbstractActivity Class

Comment: so i must create a new baseactvity class and should copy your code thats it ?

Comment: Yes But use that to reuse layout and put extra methods that you frequently use... Don't post any other unnecessary codes in that Activity. And again try extending NavigationActivity in Contact too

Comment: It's a really working example... many developers follow this pattern may be you are doing wrong... Don't try to use findViewById if the view is not related to your current activity. And are you sure you have activity_navigation ?